# How to make thirdparty URL secure

Tags: http, ssl, https

Hi I have some issue regarding SSL Page.

I have set my all link URL with

```
https://
```

But in my site some ads are coming with

```
http://
```

so it changes `HTTPS` color from green to yellow in chrome. The color should remain same that is green. so what should i do ?

Comment: Err, change your site?

Comment: @EJP I can't understand you.

Comment: Change your site so the advertisements are reached via https: rather than http:?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remain the color same because this depends on where your add is coming from. for more information you can check this https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2449877?hl=en or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33738/are-secret-urls-secure-over-https

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking but if you use http url in https page, browser will throw error. It is always recommended to check URL (be it third party or same website).

Regarding to color, if you have installed EV SSL, it may show green bar in browser. Check paypal website.

Comment: @PeggyP- i think he is talking about the in his HTTPS page, some adds are coming in HTTP. So, his HTTPS color is changed from the green to yellow